# Para usar a API do Maps do Google precisa habilitar o faturamento?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou tentando colocar um mapa no site, mas o Google diz no console do browser que precisa habilitar o faturamento.

É isso mesmo?

```
window.initMap = function(){
    if(document.getElementById('mapa')){
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-22.7499199, -43.3937669),
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        var iconBase = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.559308, -46.691324),
            icon: iconBase,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: 'Lugar'
        });

        marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
    }
}

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC0o2BROdoqZLlSNKuBxdC-ddd&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Estou fazendo assim e me retorna o seguinte problema:

> You have exceeded your request quota for this API. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages?utm_source=maps_js&utm_medium=degraded&utm_campaign=billing#api-key-and-billing-errors

Comment: Sim, senão me engano isso passou a valer em julho do ano passado!

Comment: Mas tipo, tem créditos todo mês pra usar? Você sabe alguma coisa disso?

Comment: Tabela de preço: https://developers.google.com/maps/previous-pricing

Comment: Vou ter que usar o embed.